# writing a c++ program using a cpp file with header file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++builder

Just trying to write a basic c++ program for my college project

I declared a sample class called `TestClass` and put it in the `testclass.h` file in `header files` folder.

```
class TestClass
{
private:
    int an;
public:
    TestClass(void);
    int a[];
    void print();
    void compute();
    void get();
    ~TestClass(void);
};
```

And then to `implement` the above class, I created a new file in `Source Files` folders and then wrote this piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "TestClass.h"



    TestClass:: vinayak(void)
    {

    }

    void TestClass:: print()
    {

    }
    void TestClass:: compute()
    {

    }
    void TestClass:: get()
    {

    }

    TestClass:: ~TestClass(void)
    {

    }
```

I then created a new file called `Source.cpp` and then wrote the piece of code.

```
#include "TestClass.h"
#include "TestClass.cpp"

void main()
{
    TestClass TObject = TestClass();
    TObject.get();

}
```

Here I am getting an error like below:

```
public: void __thiscall TestClass::compute(void)" already defined in Source.obj
```

Any ideas why ?

EDIT:

Based on @Marco's comment, I was able to compile the program.
Also, I had to remove the `constructor` and the `destructor` declarations in the `header file`.

This made the program to work fine :)

Comment: `int a[];` is illegal in a class definition

Comment: It would be wise to call your variables something other than `TObject` if you are using C++Builder as it uses that name for a fundamental object. E.g . use something starting with a lower-case letter for a variable name.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: thank you :) I never knew..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you write

```
#include "something"
```

it's like copy-pasting the content of that "something" file into that specific location.

You're compiling a "`TestClass`" translation unit and a "`Source`" translation unit both containing the definition of your `compute` method.

Remove the cpp include in Source.cpp:

```
#include "TestClass.h"
// #include "TestClass.cpp" <- Remove this

void main()
{
    TestClass TObject = TestClass();
    TObject.get();

}
```

and the `Source` translation unit will know `TestClass` has a `compute` method, but the [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)  (read it up) will be satisfied.

---

Summary of what you need to read about:

- Difference between declaration / definition
- What's a TU - translation unit
- Difference between compiling and linking
- What's the ODR and why it's important
- What does the `#include` directive do

Comment: A: thanks Marco. I removed the `redefinition` and everything worked great. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Header file must be protected against multiple inclusions.

Add `#pragma once` on top of your header file, or change it to:

```
#ifndef TEST_CLASS_INCLUDE
#define TEST_CLASS_INCLUDE
class TestClass
{
...
};
#endif
```

Also, you should never include .cpp files. Just include include TestClass.h from Source.cpp and make sure TestClass.cpp is compiled and TestClass.o is linked.

Jean

Comment: thank you. I have included `#pragma once` as you said. Thanks again. Not enough reputation to `upvote` :(  But thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on linking

This line

```
#include "TestClass.cpp"
```

is not required

Answer (score 0):

You are including the `TestClass.cpp`, you need to include only the header file